# Core.line is not applicable for the arguments with OpenCV4Android

Tags: android, opencv

i am getting some troubles with OpenCV4Android.

```
Core.line(mGray, pt1, pt2, new Scalar(255,0,0));
```

or:

```
Core.line(mRgba, pt1, pt2, new Scalar(255,0,0));
```

or:

```
Core.line(mRgba, pt1, pt2, new Scalar(255,0,0,0));
```

The Error from Eclipse:
The method line(Mat, Point, Point, Scalar) in the type Core is not applicable for the arguments (Mat, Point, Point, Scalar)

Does somebody knows whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there are different types of Point at OpenCV.

```
org.opencv.core.Point
```

is the correct/accepted point-type.